# Generate Monthly Aggregated Values in SQlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am new in SQLite and i have been working on SQL Query for quite some time.

Lets say we have database table say **tbl_expense** with the following table structure.

**tbl_expense**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_expense(
    expense_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    expense_name VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
    expense_desc VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL, 
    expense_type VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
    expense_amt DECIMAL(6.3) DEFAULT NULL, 
    expense_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Assume we have the following data stored in the table.

[image]

**Expected Output**

Assuming we have expense_date as timestamp, How can i write a SQL query in such a way that i can produce the output like the one below.

[image]

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: do u need this in myql or sqllite?

Comment: i need this in SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `LEFT` join of a cte that returns all the month abbreviations to the table and conditional aggregation:

```
WITH cte(month, month_name) AS (VALUES
  ('01', 'JAN'), ('02', 'FEB'), ('03', 'MAR'), ('04', 'APR'), ('05', 'MAY'), ('06', 'JUN'), 
  ('07', 'JUL'), ('08', 'AUG'), ('09', 'SEP'), ('10', 'OCT'), ('11', 'NOV'), ('12', 'DEC')
)
SELECT c.month_name,
       TOTAL(CASE WHEN expense_type = 'Income' THEN expense_amt END) Income,
       TOTAL(CASE WHEN expense_type = 'expense' THEN expense_amt END) Expense
FROM cte c LEFT JOIN tbl_expense e
ON strftime('%m', e.expense_date, 'unixepoch') = c.month
AND strftime('%Y', e.expense_date, 'unixepoch') = strftime('%Y', CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY c.month_name
ORDER BY c.month;
```

The condition:

```
strftime('%Y', e.expense_date, 'unixepoch') = strftime('%Y', CURRENT_DATE)
```

is used to return results only for the current year.
You can change it to get results for any year that you want, like:

```
strftime('%Y', e.expense_date, 'unixepoch') = '2020'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a14160a9df423a2bc195bd060d7053a0).

Comment: hi @forpas, how can i integrate the 2 SQL queries into one. I need a single query for the above problem. is it possible to achieve ?

Comment: @likithsai this is a single query. The cte is part of the query.